# Evenly distributed dashed lines with OpenGL?

Tags: c++, c, opengl, graphics

I notice that drawing dashed lines with GL will not make them even apart unless each vertex is equidistant from the last. Is there a way to simply make the whole path dashed evenly regardless of the distance between each point?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you're drawing `GL_LINES` rather than `GL_LINE_STRIPs` or `GL_LINE_LOOPs`.  With the latter, the individual segments are connected and the stipple pattern is continuous from one to the next.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the connected line primitives are potentially faster because they send half as much data to the GPU.

Comment: Surely Drew -- but it was really only a one-letter edit... :-)